# How do I find a list (size n) of integers where the root-mean-square of the list is an integer?

Tags: integers

I already found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732555/how-to-find-all-possible-values-of-four-variables-when-squared-sum-to-n), but it discusses mostly brute force. Brute force is possible of course, but are there any other ways? Is there a way to find all lists? Is there a way to find out how many combinations exist under a certain limit?

Also related: [same but for first n integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528669/what-is-the-smallest-integer-n-greater-than-1-such-that-the-root-mean-square)

Comment: One may pick $n$ of the same integer.

Comment: @YiyuanLee Sets don't have repeated elements.

Comment: @Peyton I mean list, so I changed the question

Comment: @MichielvanderBlonk So, you do want to allow repeated elements?

Comment: @Peyton exactly. But I do like them better without.

Comment: If $x^2+y^2=z^2$ then $(x-y)^2+(y+x)^2=2z^2$, so $(x-y,x+y)$ ives the case when $n=2$.

Comment: is $n$ part of the input?

Comment: @mdave16 no, just n integers

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of $n$ integers whose root-mean-square equals the integer $t$, then you are looking for solutions in integers $x_1,\dots,x_n$ of $x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2 = nt^2$. The solutions of $x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2 = K$ for an integer $K$ are pretty well-known: for example, there are elementary exact formuals for how many there are when $n=2$ and $n=4$ (at least), an elementary characterization of when they exist for $n=3$, and an asymptotic formula (existence guaranteed) for the number of solutions when $n\ge5$. So not only are there lots of ways to generate solutions, but you can even aim for your favorite value of $t$.

Comment: Do you have reference material for this?

Comment: a starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares#Number_theory